# How can I disable the Django Celery admin modules?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, celery, django-celery

I have no need to the celery modules in my Django admin. Is there a way I could remove it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To be more specific, in `admin.py` of any app inside `INSTALLED_APPS` **after** `'djcelery'`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from djcelery.models import (
    TaskState, WorkerState, PeriodicTask, 
    IntervalSchedule, CrontabSchedule)

admin.site.unregister(TaskState)
admin.site.unregister(WorkerState)
admin.site.unregister(IntervalSchedule)
admin.site.unregister(CrontabSchedule)
admin.site.unregister(PeriodicTask)
```

Comment: I got `NotRegistered at /admin/` `The model TaskState is not registered`. But I still see it in admin.

Comment: I also have this problem. This is no longer a proper solution.

Comment: @goliney I've checked this against the latest djcelery (3.1.1) and it works. Please ensure that the `unregister` code is in the `admin.py` file of any app which is AFTER `djcelery` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Otherwise Django would execute our unregister code first and sadly find that `TaskState` is not registered (because it is registered in `admin.py` of `djcelery`, which has not been run yet!).

Comment: @mh00h Please see the comment above and check whether it's the issue.

Comment: You have to import djcelery.admin first, guys.

Comment: @okm thats a perfect answer. I did rearranged my app at INSTALLED_APPS taking djcelery first. It works !!!  Thank u

Answer (score 2):

Updated version looks like:

```
from django_celery_beat.models import (
    IntervalSchedule,
    CrontabSchedule,
    SolarSchedule,
    ClockedSchedule,
    PeriodicTask,
)

admin.site.unregister(SolarSchedule)
admin.site.unregister(ClockedSchedule)
admin.site.unregister(PeriodicTask)
admin.site.unregister(IntervalSchedule)
admin.site.unregister(CrontabSchedule)
```

You always can get a list of registered models via:

```
admin.site._registry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unregister celerys models like admin.site.unregister(CeleryModelIdoNotWantInAdmin)