# Unregister Djcelery from from Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin, celery, django-celery

I am using celery in django but will be using flower in place of the djcelery django-admin administation panel. How can I remove djcelery from the admin?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571960/how-can-i-disable-the-django-celery-admin-modules

Comment: I get NotRegistered at /admin/ The model TaskState is not registered and still see it in admin. The answer there is outdated I think.